# Python and Neo4j - creating a RESTful API

Tags: python, django, rest, neo4j, py2neo

I have spent quite a bit of time researching the different Python frameworks for neo4j (i.e. neo4django, bulbflow, py2neo), and have been very impressed at how they are able to abstract the functionality to make it feel like working with familiar relational databases.  The question I have is around setting up a stack that allows for some of this abstraction for things like model creation, oauth, and basic querying but to incorporate graph-based algorithms for data analysis, more detailed traversals and path finding, etc.

Is there a recommended or tried approach for creating a robust RESTful API with the available libraries and capabilities of Django, and the freedom to drop down to the lower level neo4j API when necessary?  Having some control over the cypher queries would be great, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if something like neo4django has already implemented the basics very well.  It is a bit daunting deciding how to set this all up from scratch, and there seem to be a lot of possibilities, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

For example, since py2neo is built on top of the neo4j REST API, and I then use it to work with Django and Tastypie as a separate REST API, which is accessed by a mobile or web app, do these layers of abstraction get redundant or even start to take away from the usefulness?  Again, any input from people who have worked with graph databases and python is definitely helpful.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I would also really like to take advantage of some of the neo4j libraries out there, such as spatial, so the extra abstraction in some of the existing solutions may be counter-productive -- again, I'm not sure though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Neo4django and Neomodel are built on client libraries (neo4jrestclient and py2neo respectively) so you can in theory drop down to lower level functionality with either of those projects as required.

I also built a (very basic) [Object-Graph Mapping module](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/ogm/) for py2neo which is intended to be a base for custom object mapping layers. In light of some of the big enhancements in Neo4j 2.0 though, I have a number of improvements planned for this module as and when I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

I was debating with myself if I should answer as the repo and the python package is outdated but I guess more information is better.

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/johanlundberg/neo4j-django-tutorial) where Django is used with neo4j-embedded. I went this way to be able to build what ever REST API I wanted (tastypie) and use the very fast embedded db.

That said, as Neo4j approaches 2.0 I would think twice of investing to much in the embedded db and Python. Neo4j's REST server seems the way to go.